# regular expression matching 4 letter word

Tags: expression

I am doing fine with most regular expressions, however I can't seem to write a regular expression to match a 4 letter word in the middle of a line. I have torn through my notes for 2 days and cant find it. Either I fell asleep at that point or it was not covered by mistake. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A quick'n'dirty regexp would be `/\s[^\s]{4}\s/` but could you provide an example string to test?

Comment: Thats another issue. The question is flat. I'm being asked to write a regular expression that matches a 4 letter word in the middle of a line. Professor is not very good with leading you in the right direction to learn.